# toggle UISwitch in app when user hits home button

Tags: swift

I use Swift and Xcode6.2, I have a view controller say X in tabViewController. X has a UISwitch to toggle torch, when the UISwitch is ON and user hits the home button (app goes in background)

when app becomes active again
1. torch is OFF
2. but torch switch is ON

I want to switch off the torch switch too
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following code in the `viewDidLoad` function of X:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
  selector: "appDidEnterBackground:",
  name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification,
  object: nil)
```

X will then receive a [UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification) when your app enters the background, and the `appDidEnterBackground` function will be called. You need to implement this function in X to switch the UISwitch off:

```
func appDidEnterBackground(notification: NSNotification){
    theSwitch.on = false
}
```